# How can I configure Windows 10 EFI/Bootloader?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub2

I am currently using a dual-boot setup with Windows 10 and Linux, which were on the same physical drive until today. I just purchased a new drive, and decided to move my Windows partition to the new drive and resize my Linux partition to utilize the entirety of the old drive. I left the EFI, Windows recovery environment and Microsoft Reserved partiotions as they were on my old hard drive.

After moving the Windows partion in Parted Live, I used an arch linux recovery USB to `arch-chroot` and run `grub-mkconfig` with `os-prober.` Os prober found the windows bootloader, but it appears that what it found was is the EFI stub(? sorry, hazy on the terminology but I'm trying to learn) in the EFI partition. So, GRUB2 seems to work fine, I'm able to select OSs and Arch Linux boots correctly. When I try to boot windows, it errors out and tries to repair until it quits. It seems obvious that the EFI entry for windows does not know to point to the partition's new location, but I can't seem to find any information on how to remedy that.

Right now, I'm in the process of trying to clone the efi and Microsoft Reserved partions from the old disk to the new one, setting my mobo firmware to boot that disk, and seeing where I can get with my Windows 10 recovery media. To do that, I'm having resize and move my Windows partition to make room for the two partitions I'll be cloning. Side note, but even though the Windows partition only has about 120GB utilized, GParted is moving around 900GB of data, which is taking an enormous amount of time.

Does anyone have any information that could possibly be helpful for someone in my situation?

Edit: For transparency, I also asked this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569318/how-can-i-boot-a-windows-10-partition-that-is-on-a-different-drive-than-my-efi-p)

Comment: You've self-answered, but for posterity: bcdedit to modify an existing bootloader (incl. changing the target volume); bcdboot to install a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody panic, I have found the answer to this hotbed of a question. Hopefully this doesn't get lost in all the replies.

For anyone who searches for anything like this in the future, the solution for me was to completely nuke the EFI partition (via parted live, or your favorite rescue partition manager). From there, I created a new fat32 formatted partition that was 256mb at the end of my first drive and called it EFI. Some guides will tell you that this partition has to be at the start of the drive, but according to the UEFI specification, that's not true.

Then, I booted a Windows 10 installation USB. Entered the command prompt, and used some built-in functions to generate new boot files. I mostly followed a guide found [here](https://www.anyrecover.com/hard-drive-recovery-data/how-to-create-and-delete-efi-system-partition-in-windows/), but for more details, you can search for 'how to create efi partition windows.'

After that, I couldn't boot Linux, but the process of installing and configuring a dual-boot capable bootloader with a linux rescue CD is trivial and well documented.